# how to report about method situation via progress bar wpf C#

Tags: c#, progress-bar

i am working on project in C# and its contain a methods that need a long time to be executed so i need a progress bar that tell the user about how much remain and i don't know how . 
i google for it and i see courses about **BackgroundWorker**  and still don't know how to use it

```
 private void Lock_Methods()
    {
        foreach (FolderInfo fi in FolderInfo)
        {
           // code need a lot of time ....
            }



        }
```

any help please ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker()
{ WorkerReportsProgress = true };
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
```

And

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   for(int i = 0: i < FolderInfo.Count; i++)
   {
      //... 
      (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress((int)(100/FolderInfo.Count)*i, null);
   }
}

private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```